# Conversion of JSON to CSV using Javascript doesnt give Keys

Tags: javascript, json, export-to-csv

I have converted JSON to CSV using JavaScript but in a bizarre fashion, I don't see the headers being transferred to CSV file. I only see the corresponding values.

Below is the example of

1) JSON ....

```
[
  {
    "entityid": 2,
    "personid": 45676
  }
]
```

2) JavaScript code ....

```
function DownloadJSON2CSV(objArray)
    {
        alert(objArray);
        var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;

        var str = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            var line = '';

            for (var index in array[i]) {
                //line += array[i][index] + ',';
            if (line != '') line += ','
                line += array[i][index];


            }

            alert(line);
            // Here is an example where you would wrap the values in double quotes
            // for (var index in array[i]) {
            //    line += '"' + array[i][index] + '",';
            // }

            //line.slice(0,line.Length-1); 

            str += line + '\r\n';
        }

        alert(str);
        window.open( "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(str)) 

    }
```

3) CSV Output ....

2,45676

---

I should see the keys - `entityid` and `personid` also in CSV in the first line of the document, but I don't.

Comment: Which part of your code is responsible for including property keys into a string?

Comment: Guess this is the part where I am missing the keys - entityid, personid -----> for (var index in array[i]) {
                //line += array[i][index] + ',';
            if (line != '') line += ','
                line += array[i][index];


            }

Comment: As long as you absolutely sure that your JSON will always have flat and consistent structure, you just need to add `index` to the string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes my JSONs are going to be flat with no objects inside but I didn't get what you meant by add index to the string. Could you detail more please ?

Answer (score 1):

**This code will extract headers from the json keys additionally it will double quote the fields which include commas in it.**

```
function convertToCSV(objArray) {
    var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;
    var str = '';
    var keys = [];
    for(var k in objArray[0]) keys.push(k);
     for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
     {
         if(i==keys.length-1){str=str+keys[i]+'\r\n'}
             else {str=str+keys[i]+','}
         }
     for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var line = '';
        for (var index in array[i]) {
            if (line != '') line += ','
               if(array[i][index].toString().includes(",") && typeof array[i][index] === 'string'){array[i][index]="\""+array[i][index]+"\""}
                   line += array[i][index];
           }
           str += line + '\r\n';
       }
       return str;
   }
```

**Usage: (for Node.js)**

```
var fs = require('fs'); //**run** npm install fs **if not installed yet in cmd**
var arrayOfObjects = [{"id":28,"Title":"Sweden"}, {"id":56,"Title":"USA"},{"id":89,"Title":"England"}];
fs.writeFile("./test.csv", convertToCSV(arrayOfObjects));
```

Answer (score 0):

You hadn't set it up to output the header line.

```
function DownloadJSON2CSV(objArray)
    {
        var array = typeof objArray != 'object' ? JSON.parse(objArray) : objArray;

        var str = '';
        var headers = new Array();

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            var line = '';
            var data = array[i];
            for (var index in data) {
                headers.push(index);
                if (line != '') {
                    line += ','
                }
                line += '"' + array[i][index] + '"';

                console.log('line: ' + line);
            }
            str += line + ((array.length>1) ? '\r\n' : '');
            line = '';
        }

        headers = ArrNoDupe(headers);

        console.log('headers: ' + headers);
        console.log('str: ' + str);
        str = headers + '\r\n' + str;
        console.log('final str: ' + str);
        window.open( "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(str));

    }

    function ArrNoDupe(a) {
        var temp = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            temp[a[i]] = true;
        var r = [];
        for (var k in temp)
            r.push(k);
        return r;
    }
```

CSV outputs like so...

entityid,personid

"2","45676"

Comment: Thank you @daddygames ... this works. I am figuring out how you added comma in the header between the entityid and personid ... thank you so much.

Comment: I would just extract headers from the first object in the array.

Comment: @PM77-1 the reason I did it this way was so that if objects have additional properties, the names of those additional properties can be added to the header as well. The trouble with this is making sure it comes out consistent between objects with varying properties. I didn't code for consistency in that manner.

Comment: @Esh when you append an array object to a string, the runtime automagically converts the array to a comma-separated string value

Comment: Oh gotcha. Was wondering how that's working, now it makes sense. Thank you.