# Javascript: How to convert an JSON arrays in array into an CSV file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, csv

I'm struggeling with my JSON file here...
This is what I get from my processing .php-file as a response:

```
{"1":{"Nachname":"Stromberg","Vorname":"Bernd", 
"Benutzername":"strombergbernd12","Password":"Xrz5Bv6A"},
"2":{"Nachname":"Heisterkamp","Vorname":"Ernie", 
"Benutzername":"heisterkampernie12","Password":"aOq24EpF"}}
```

Now, I want to build from this JSON array a csv file. In the first row the csv file should mention the headers Nachname, Vorname, Benutzername and Password and then list in the following rows the rest of the data.

I cant handle that, can you help me?

Comment: What do you mean, "I can't handle that"? What have you tried?

Comment: well, I tried different codes of converting arrays and json's to csv files, but all I get is junk or nothing in the csv in the end.

Comment: You start from a JSON. CSV are Comma Separated Values. Therefore, you need to transform your data before exporting it to CSV. What's the expected output?

Comment: You need to include the *different codes* you've tried on your post.

Comment: Here is a hint, to get the headers for your csv, you can use `Object.keys()`

Comment: The output can be inside the csv:
Nachname, Vorname, Benutzername, Password \n
Stromberg, Bernd, strombergbernd12, Xrz5Bv6A

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48213639/conversion-of-json-to-csv-using-javascript-doesnt-give-keys/48214624#48214624

Comment: This is technically not an array but an object with integer as keys. Main difference is that you won't get the Array prototype on the object after parsing it

Comment: @daddygames https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48213639/conversion-of-json-to-csv-using-javascript-doesnt-give-keys/48214624#48214624
this just writes in browser log "headers: str: final str:" but literally nothing else.

Comment: @Dawko I'm glad you got an answer here. However, I think you missed the code in the link I provided that shows everything being opening in a new window, which results in a CVS output in that new window -> window.open( "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(str));

Answer (score 8, accepted):

once you have your json as text you parse it:

```
var json = JSON.parse(jsonAsText);
```

transform it to an array:

```
json = Object.values(json);
```

init your result:

```
var csv = "";
```

keep header keys somewhere:

```
var keys = (json[0] && Object.keys(json[0])) || [];
```

write header row

```
csv += keys.join(',') + '\n';
```

iterate and put everything in csv

```
for (var line of json) {
  csv += keys.map(key => line[key]).join(',') + '\n';
}
```

Your csv content should be ready

```js
var json = {
  "1": {
    "Nachname": "Stromberg",
    "Vorname": "Bernd",
    "Benutzername": "strombergbernd12",
    "Password": "Xrz5Bv6A"
  },
  "2": {
    "Nachname": "Heisterkamp",
    "Vorname": "Ernie",
    "Benutzername": "heisterkampernie12",
    "Password": "aOq24EpF"
  }
}

function toCSV(json) {
  json = Object.values(json);
  var csv = "";
  var keys = (json[0] && Object.keys(json[0])) || [];
  csv += keys.join(',') + '\n';
  for (var line of json) {
    csv += keys.map(key => line[key]).join(',') + '\n';
  }
  return csv;
}

console.log(toCSV(json));
```

---

Note: If you can, switch your json to Array syntax:

```
[
  {
    "Nachname":"Stromberg",
    "Vorname":"Bernd",
    "Benutzername":"strombergbernd12",
    "Password":"Xrz5Bv6A"
  },
  {
    "Nachname":"Heisterkamp",
    "Vorname":"Ernie", 
    "Benutzername":"heisterkampernie12",
    "Password":"aOq24EpF"
  }
]
```

and then remove this line:

```
json = Object.values(json);
```

Comment: wow, you're a genius! I'm not used to json & javascript at all. Sorry for my dumb question - must have been pretty obvious to you.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that `json = Object.values(json);` is a waste of ressource. If you can you should use the array syntax in your json (`["item1", "item2", ...]`) and remove this line

Comment: `$header = array('Nachname', 'Vorname');
$results[$number] += array_combine($header, array($usernachname, $uservorname));
$results[$number] += array_combine($header, array($postuname, $pass));`

How can I build your kind of Array? I dont get how to build it, and without the indexes, how can I call one specific item? Wait, actually I dont need to call one specific item...

Comment: Got it through a second array:
`$user = array(); $user +=  ['Nachname' => $usernachname]; 
$user +=  ['Vorname' => $uservorname]; $user +=  ['Benutzername' => $postuname];
 $user +=  ['Password' => $pass];
 $results[] = $user;`

Comment: Had to replace your "for(var line of json)" to make it IE11 compatible.
Danny's code helped me:
`for (var item in json) {
    csv += Object.values(json[item]).join(",");
    csv += "\n";
  }`

Answer (score 0):

You could use: [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  var data = {
    "1": {
      "Nachname": "Stromberg",
      "Vorname": "Bernd",
      "Benutzername": "strombergbernd12",
      "Password": "Xrz5Bv6A"
    },
    "2": {
      "Nachname": "Heisterkamp",
      "Vorname": "Ernie",
      "Benutzername": "heisterkampernie12",
      "Password": "aOq24EpF"
    }
  };
  var csv = Object.keys(data[Object.keys(data)[0]]).join(","); // Header columns.
  csv += "\n";
  for (var item in data) {
    csv += Object.values(data[item]).join(",");
    csv += "\n";
  }
  console.log(csv);
}());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}
```

The result will be:

[image]

Comment: data[1] will fail with a single item ;)

Comment: @Apolo Fixed it. Thank you for the observation.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez took your `for (var item in json)` line to make it IE11 compatible - thank you!